# Google analytics failed to record product list click in product list performance

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using enhanced e-commerce in GA and want to set up product list performance. While it can record "product list view" and "product add to cart", "product list click" cannot be recorded. May I know anything I did was wrong? Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the event is sent to Analytics upon clicking on the product? Try to see the event action report.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. Only Product impression and Add to cart are recorded. But the tag did fired when product click was performed. Is there any way to check where's the issue is? Thanks a lot Michele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your first image, the one of the tag configuration (m2 - productClick), and your confirmation to my comment to your main post, I think I understand where the problem is:

You have **enabled the overriding settings in that tag** but in Tracking ID field **you put the Google Analytics Setting variable instead of the ID of Property** (UA-...), so you must remove the setting variable from that field or enter a valid Analytics Property ID.